# Sending SNS notifications when there is an IAM Change

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudtrail

I set an SNS notification to send me an email whenever there is a change regarding the IAM policies. When a change occurs, CloudTrail sends a Log to CloudWatch which triggers an alarm attached to an SNS topic. More details in this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-receive-alerts-when-your-iam-configuration-changes/).

Here is an example of what I get by mail:

```
Alarm Details:
- Name:                       PolicyAlarm
- Description:                This alarm is to monitor IAM Changes
- State Change:               INSUFFICIENT_DATA -> ALARM
- Reason for State Change:    Threshold Crossed: 1 datapoint [1.0 (31/08/17 09:15:00)] was greater than or equal to the threshold (1.0).
- Timestamp:                  Thursday 31 August, 2017 09:20:39 UTC
- AWS Account:                00011100000

Threshold:
- The alarm is in the ALARM state when the metric is GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold 1.0 for 300 seconds.
```

The only relevant information here is the `AWS Account ID`. Is there a way to also include the change? Who made it, when and where? Or maybe send little information from the cloudwatch log like the `"eventName"` ?

Comment: Evaluate AWS Config. It would give you the current configuration. Write a logic to determine the change. Regarding who made the change, you need to look at CloudTrail logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to trigger notifications from an AWS CloudTrail:

1. Configure **Amazon CloudWatch Logs** to look for specific strings. When found, it increments a **metric**. Then, create an alarm that triggers when the metric exceeds a particular value over a particular period of time. When the notification is sent, only information about the **alarm** is sent. OR...
2. Create a rule in **Amazon CloudWatch Events** to look for the event. Set an Amazon SNS topic as the target. When the notification is sent, **full details of the event are passed through**.

You should use # 2, since it provides full details of the event.

Here's what I did to test:

- Created an **Amazon SQS queue** in `us-east-1` (where all IAM events take place)
- Created an **Amazon CloudWatch Events rule** in `us-east-1` with:

  - **Service Name:** IAM
  - **Event Type:** AWS API Call via CloudTrail
  - **Specific Operations:** PutUserPolicy
- Edited an IAM policy

Within a short time, the event appeared in SQS:

Here's the relevant bits of the policy that came through:

```
{
  "detail-type": "AWS API Call via CloudTrail",
  "source": "aws.iam",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": "iam.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "PutUserPolicy",
    "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
    "requestParameters": {
      "policyDocument": "{\n    \"Version\": \"2012-10-17\",\n  ...  }",
      "policyName": "my-policy",
      "userName": "my-user"
    },
    "eventType": "AwsApiCall"
  }
}
```

I sent the message to SQS, but you could also send it to SNS to then forward via email.

Comment: I'm trying that, and I see that IAM is not available in the list of **Service Name**. Could you please tell me which to select? Thank you

Comment: Are you doing it in `us-east-1` (N.Virginia)?

Comment: No. In eu-west-1 (Irlande)

Comment: Also, I tried doing what you did, but I don't get more information in the email. the Event rule is not targeting the SNS

Comment: You must use us-east-1 to configure IAM in CloudWatch Events. You must configure the Event Rule (eg in the console) to configure a target. Oh, you also have to **adjust the permissions on the SQS queue to allow messages to be received**. I just allowed all actions from anywhere, but for real usage you should lock it down further.

Comment: that is unfortunate if I can't use irland region ... Thank you I'll look further.

Comment: So I should have the CloudWatch rule in N. Virginia

Comment: The Topic field does not take the ARN of the other region. I paste it and it goes blank

Comment: Oops. I was mistaken. It *cannot* send to a different region. My apologies.

Comment: That's alright. Is it possible to set the service Name to CloudWatch Logs or Events ? Since CloudTrail sends the IAM change to it?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks fa lot for us-east-1 for IAM, input! Saved my day.